# Trying to setup a custom backBarButtonItem image / difficulty with resizable image

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am trying to replace the default backBarButtonItem image used by UINavigationControllers in my app. I want to use the following image (actually I am using a white arrow, but that wouldn't show here against the white background):

[image]

My image is 60 pixels wide and 33 pixels high, including empty space buffer around the arrow that I want to use to keep the arrow from being stretched too wide.

I've added the following code to my AppDelegate.m

```
UIImage *barButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-navbar-backbutton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,27,0,0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The left inset is set to 27 points so that the head of the arrow isn't stretched. But when I run the code, I get the following result in the nav bar:

[image]

Why am I getting the extra white piece at the end of my backBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting that result because the default mode for increasing the size of the image is tiling. So, you're tiling some of the white part and some of the black to the right of your arrow. You need to add enough of an inset on the right to get you into the white part of the image, so that the only thing tiling is the straight line part of the arrow.

Comment: OK great, the tiling is behaviour that I've observed, but I didn't clue in to what was happening. I thought the image was supposed to be stretched. This makes sense, I'm going to test it out.